# Profile picture not showing in mysite person.aspx (Branding)

Tags: 2013, user-profile, my-site, branding

Im attaching an image of how a users page looks like in My Site. As you can see the organization chart and some user attributes shows up like expected.

However, the user profile picture doesnt show up because of custom branding that someone else performed. Im comparing this to the seattle.html masterpage but cannot make the profile picture visible, the one thats usually visible to the left above a menu.

[image: Person.aspx on Mysite]

Answer (score 1):

Can you restore the default Master? Can you look in the UPA and ensure that the profile has a photo associated with it? Once you have done those two things I would then look to tools like Firebug or IE Developer Tools to figure out the issue.

Start with restoring the original master.

Comment: If I restore the default master (seattle.master), then the image is visible.

Comment: OK, so it's your branding. Can you fix it now?

Comment: Yes it is my branding html/masterfile that messes this up. I want to know what code segments I need to add to it in order for the profile picture to show.

Answer (score 0):

i cant see the image :( its blocked at my work but could you inspect the element using F12 developer on IE? is the image url correct, does it display an x? make sure that the css is not the cause of the problem if for example they changed the position attribute or display attribute, you can fiddle about in f12 developer to get the image back up.

im going with css, get f12 developer running, click on the pointer and then click on the image... now inspect the css for that element and see what .css files are branding that element.... going by what you stated I would expect to see some branding from a custom css file where its overriding the default branding ;).... if it is than change it within the f12 developer tools to get it back and then you can change the css file the same values as you did on f12 developer tools!